# MutableLiveData VS LveData

Tags: java, android, kotlin, livedata

```
  private val _ld = MutableLiveData<Int>()
  val ld: LiveData<Int> = _ld

  (ld as MutableLiveData).value = 78
```

Данный код, на удивление, оказался полностью рабочим.
я могу изменять ЛайвДату из мест, где я должен **только** ее слушать.
какой смысл продолжать писать Лайвдаты через shadow properti??

есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы такой "обход" системы был невозможен или приводил к ошибке??

Comment: Сокрытием реального типа вы гарантируете пользователю кода только базовый функционал и оставляете за собой право изменить реализацию, не сломав пользовательский код. Ничто не помешает использовать функционал реального типа - в конце концов есть рефлексия. И если кто-то сделал такой финт - это его проблемы.

Comment: Как вариант, не выставляйте лайвдату наружу вообще - пусть класс принимает колбек и сам его подписывает на лайвдату.

Comment: Еще можно написать свой LiveData прокси, который будет скрывать что он мутабельный внутри.

Comment: Интересно, а такой фокус проходит с `StateFlow`?

Comment: @Barmaley попробовал - да, проходит.  ` val _a = MutableStateFlow(8);  val a: Flow<Int> = _a`

Comment: @Barmaley нет, если делать `mutableStateFlow.asStateFlow()`, если делать как в посте с LiveData, то можно, это обычный upcasting